# How to generate program dependence graph for C program?

Tags: c, graph, static-analysis

I want to generate a Program Dependence Graph (PDG) from C source code. I found papers that explain how do it, but all used the commercial CodeSurfer tool.

Are there any free tools that do this?

Comment: If you want to compute a PDG for a C program, why do you tag your question `C++`? It is significantly harder to analyze C++ programs to the same depth C programs can be analyzed.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a decent PDG "generator"? The PDG generated by Frama-c produces a very strage graph...

Answer (score 11):

[Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) is an open-source static analysis framework that can compute a *sound* Program Dependency Graph for C programs. Its [slicing plug-in](http://frama-c.com/slicing.html) uses the resulting PDG. The slicing and PDG computation were discussed in [February 2010](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2010-February/) on the mailing list (messages from jung, myung-jin and their answers).

You may also look at NIST's [Unravel](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/unravel/unravel.html), or Georgia Tech's [Aristotle](http://pleuma.cc.gatech.edu/aristotle/Tools/aas.html). Both [Valsoft](http://pp.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/project.php?id=30) at Karlsruhe University, and Loyola's [Surgeon's Assistant](http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~kbg/Surgeon/), might also be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual) can generate function caller and callee graphs, as well as all the functions used in your program.  This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it could provide some useful data.

[SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) is a metrics tool that can show function and program complexity as well as complexity diagrams.

Both tools are free.

Comment: A "Program Dependency Graph" is a graph whose nodes are statements and whose edges represent dependencies. It is not a call graph (whose nodes are functions). You can see an example of PDG here, but when dealing with a real programming language, especially C, the devil is in the details, and it shows in the representation. http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/attachments/20100210/87fe9543/attachment-0001.png

Answer (score 1):

There's a promising new tool called [`cpp-depenencies`](https://github.com/tomtom-international/cpp-dependencies).

It can generate `component` dependency diagrams (like below) as well as `class` hierarchy diagrams (by passing an option to treat each source file as a component).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use llvm to generate pdg, you can use this:
https://bitbucket.org/psu_soslab/program-dependence-graph-in-llvm/src/master/