# Any good ways to solve recursively header including problem?

Tags: c++, c

I am struggling with recursively cpp header including problem. To solve this problem, I have to draw the including path by hand to see where recursively including happen.

I wonder whether there are some good ways to solve this problem like a recursively including detector or a header include path painter, not a good coding style to prevent this problem(I know this is more important).

Comment: i think you may mean "cyclical" not "recursive", and if so the answer is forward declarations

Comment: Are you talking about this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: Please show a [mre], and decide which language you use; C and C++ are different. BTW, code styles help avoid such problems...

Comment: **Header Guards** and **Forward Declarations** are designed to solve issues related to circular includes.

Comment: And perhaps look at `#pragma once`?

Comment: So you are asking for a *tool* that may help in preventing the issue and to graph the dependencies, rather then a solution like the proposed dupe. Have you already read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904651/how-to-generate-program-dependence-graph-for-c-program ?

Answer (score 1):

Put `#pragma once` in the beginning of each header file, this will ensure that the header file is only included **once**.

Comment: Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once): "In the C and C++ programming languages, `#pragma once` is a **non-standard**...".  The portable way is to use [header guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).